# What to install on SSD?

Tags: ssd

I have just added a SSD drive to my PC to boost performance and now I am deciding for each application whether to install on the HDD or on the SSD.

Would you install Microsofts Visual Studio 2010 and Microsofts Expression Studio on the SSD in order to fasten up their performance or would it be wasted space ?

Comment: If you want it to start quickly, put it on the SSD, else not.

Comment: Welcome to [su]! I'm afraid this question doesn't sound like a good fit for our Q-A style because it will be difficult to create concrete requirements to define a correct answer, and any answers will be highly localized (i.e., specific to you and you alone). If you have enough rep, you might try asking around in the [Chat], where open discussion on topics like this *is* both permitted and welcome. :)

Comment: @DarthAndroid Thanks for your welcome :) Regarding my question I am confused: Isn't it a general issue whether to install an application on a SSD or a HDD ? Why wouldn't someone else profit from the answer ? Most of the questions throughout all Stack Exchange sites are about specific and localized issues of the people ... So I don't see the difference here ...

Comment: @Marc While true in a general sense, the issue is the choice of applications is highly personal. I might want games on my SSD, and not Visual Studio. You might want Visual Studio because you don't have any games (work system maybe?). Any general answers will be too vague to be useful ("Whatever you use most!"), and anything specific enough to answer the question for you will likely be too specific (there's not enough of a middle ground). P.S.: Move your projects to the SSD, and MSVS2010/MSES2010 if you still have room ;)

Comment: Also note that we have plenty of questions dealing with the subject already — what to install where seems like a very common problem, but always a very localized one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install everything you can on your SSD.

When it gets close to filling up, use something like WinDirStat to identify the large folders (in "Program Files", leave your Windows folder(s) well alone), move them across to your HDD and use NTFS Junctions to create a link from the old location on the SSD to the new location on your HDD.

You could probably evaluate each application for the pros and cons of moving it based on disk access and file size but - quite frankly - life is probably too short so I'd just consider how often you use something as it may be better to move a slightly smaller (but lesser used) folder.